# About jQuery issues that how to return css value of tag in multiple i try with single it returns fine but multiple not

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var propertyValue = $('.nav-bar-box').css(["width", "height", "background-color"]);
alert(propertyValue);
```

I write this and value [object, object]

Is there anyone help me?

Comment: ```alert()``` cannot display ```object```. For debugging issue use ```console.log()``` instead of alert.

Comment: If you still want to display the value of object, use JSON.stringify and pass that value in alert function. `alert(JSON.stringify(propertyValue))`

Comment: hello brijesh i tried with this way the message show undefined

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple css property, You have to use this syntax:

```
// change css on any action
$('.nav-bar-box').css({"width": "height", "background-color": "red"});
```

*Note:- **Curly braces just like in javascript classes.** Here is the w3school example [css_jquery_multiple](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp)

Comment: thank you but i want to get css value by jquery not add by jquery